# Ng-Tag-input minLength not set property

Tags: ng-tags-input

I use this library in my ionic project (Cross platform mobile application), And I try to set minLength : 1 but it takes default value (i.e. 3). How can i achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide the markup you are using?

Comment: tagsInputConfigProvider
        .setDefaults('tagsInput', {
            placeholder: 'New tag',
            minLength: 1,
            addOnEnter: false,
            keyProperty: 'Name',
            displayProperty:'Name'
        })
        .setDefaults('autoComplete', {
            debounceDelay: 200,
            loadOnDownArrow: true,
            loadOnEmpty: true
        })

Answer (score 1):

Set the `min-length="1"` property to the `<auto-complete>` instead of `<tags-input>` to get suggestions for every character.

like this:

```
       <tags-input ng-model="vm.tags">
            <auto-complete source="vm.loadTags($query)"
                           min-length="1" 
                           highlightMatchedText="true">
            </auto-complete>
       </tags-input>
```

Even I spent a few hours figuring out how to do it, it later flashed me when I read the documentation of **autoComplete** again.

http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api#autoComplete